# js window.open sometimes not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

I have a `js` file which contains following code:

```
function submitForm() {

//......

window.open('/projectA/spring_controller1',"_blank");

window.location = '/projectA/spring_controller2';
}
```

In most case(about 99%), `window.open` works.

But sometimes(about 1%), there is no new tab is open in chrome 73(In this case, I am sure function `submitForm` has been called, because `window.location` works, only `window.open` failed.).

In chrome, when I first execute this function, `window.open` not open a new tab while `window.location` redirect current tab to new page success. `window.open` still not work when I run this function second time. However, it can open a new tab on following executions.

After I upgrade chrome, `window.open` cannot open new tab and `window.location` work at first time, but they work on following executions.

**It seems that when this function is called at initially in chrome(initial call at current version or upgrade to new version), `window.open` cannot open new tab, while after that it can.**

Comment: It would have happened because the function might have not called. Did you get any error?

Comment: check the permission on chrome pop_up on site setting https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcYgW.png

Comment: @saurabh I am sure the function has been called. There is no any error shown in chrome console.

Comment: @prasanth if it is caused by the permission on chrome popup, then it should always work or always not work, right? But my case is sometimes not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if any pop-up or ad-blockers plugins causing this problem,otherwise your code would have ran in to some error before hitting the window.open line of code.if it is chrome,press F12 and go to debugger option,you may be able to see any error happened before the code hitting window.open line of code.

Hope it helps.:-)

Comment: There is not any error shown on chrome console before hitting the `window.open`. Some coworkers also encounter this case besides me - sometimes `window.open` not work, so maybe this is not pop-up or ad-blockers plugins problem. Meanwhile, I only have `Biing Search Engine`, `Stylish` and `Display #Anchors` extensions in my chrome.

Comment: In that case i would recommend adding debugger; statement before this window.open and check for some 10 times.

Comment: Some other possibilities are      1.The script may be long running script,which may be timed-out.   2.try clearing cache and load the site.

Comment: `window.location` right following `window.open`, while `window.location` always work, just `window.open` sometimes not work, so I think this is not timed-out problem. I also try clearing cache and load the site, but not work.